# Using finite element galerkin to solve the heat equation (homogeneous bcs)

Tags: python, runge-kutta-methods, galerkin-methods

I 'm trying to solve the 4  types of heat equations homogeneous linear, non-homogeneous and non linear. This is the code that I have written for linear homogeneous case for beta = -1 and N of your choice. I have used hat functions with x step size = H and time I 'm wishing to take $H^2$. The problem is that if I 'm using scipy's runge kutta's method with automatic step size it's giving me this graph [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oq0s2.jpg) which suddenly gives high error at 256 basis but for basis less than this I 'm getting the error = c $H^p$  log taken relationship. So I can't say it's converging but it's taking too much time for further computation. If I run the algo_2 in the code which I have copied from geeksforgeeks or even if I write own as given on wikipedia I get infinite in just 4 time loop. Can someone please tell me what's wrong here? 
Equation is $u_t + \beta u_{xx} = f(x, t)$ and the weak derivative form uses $\phi_j$ as the hat functions in [0,  1]. I 'm trying to compute the values at t=1. I am also attaching the link to github.
https://github.com/XtremeGood/Maths-SOP/tree/corrected_boundary_conditions/working%201
Please check the corrected_boundary_conditions branch's working1 folder for the graph image and files if it doesn't open.

```
class Heat:

    #A *alpha - beta(D *) +beta(E(1 - 0)alpha) = 0


    def __init__(self, N=10):

        self.N = N
        self.H = 1/N
        self.domain = np.linspace(0, 1, N+1) 
        self.beta = -1
        self.t = 1
        #Set initial conditions here
        self.alpha = np.sin(np.pi* self.domain)
        #Set solution here
        self.exact = lambda t:math.exp(t) * self.alpha
        #Define boundary conditions
        self.b_c_start = lambda t:0
        self.b_c_end = lambda t:0

        #Define f
        def f(k):

            if k == 0:
                return (-(math.pi*self.H - math.sin(math.pi*self.H))*(math.pi**2*self.beta - 1)/(math.pi**2*self.H))
            elif k == N:
                return ((-math.pi*self.H + math.sin(math.pi*self.H))*(math.pi**2*self.beta - 1)/(math.pi**2*self.H))
            else:
                return (2*(math.pi**2*self.beta - 1)*(math.cos(math.pi*self.H) - 1)*math.sin(math.pi*self.H*k)/(math.pi**2*self.H))



        def c_dash_transform(l):

            l[0] /= self.A[0]
            for i in range(1, self.N):
                  l[i] = (l[i])/ (self.A[i]-(self.H/6)* l[i-1])

            return l        



        self.A = self.H* np.array([1/3] + [2/3]*(N-1) + [1/3])
        #         self.A = (self.H) * sp.csc_matrix(diags([       [1/6 for i in range(N)],   \
        #                                         [1/3] + [2/3]*(N-1) + [1/3], \
        #                                              [1/6 for i in range(N)] ], \
        #                                                    [1, 0, -1]), dtype=np.float32)

        self.c_dash = c_dash_transform(self.H *np.array( [1/6]*(N)))

        #-beta*


        self.D = N * sp.csr_matrix(diags([      [-1 for i in range(N)],  \
                                      [1] + [2]*(N-1) + [1], \
                                        [-1 for i in range(N)]],  \
                             [1, 0, -1] ), dtype=np.float32)
        self.D[0, 0] -= N     
        self.D[0, 1] -= -N
        self.D[N, N-1] -= -N
        self.D[N, N] -= N


        self.F = np.array([f(k) for k in prange(N+1)]).reshape(-1, 1) #incomplete without exp(t)




    def error(self):
        return np.linalg.norm(self.exact(self.t) -  self.approx, 2)




    def func (self, t,  y):

        bc_s = [self.b_c_start(t),self.b_c_end(t)]


        def apply_bc(y):
            y[0, 0], y[-1, 0] = bc_s
            return y


        def thomas_algorithm(d ):    
            d[0] /= self.A[0]
            for i in range(1, self.N + 1):
                d[i, 0] = (d[i, 0] - (self.H/6)*d[i-1])/(self.A[i]-(self.H/6)*self.c_dash[i-1])
            for i in range(self.N-1, -1, -1): # Last entry is left unchanged ;see that i+1
                d[i, 0] -= self.c_dash[i]*d[i+1]  
            return d    

        y = apply_bc(y)
        d = self.beta*self.D*y + math.exp(t)*self.F   # A alpha' = d               
        d = thomas_algorithm(d)    # alpha' = d 
        d = apply_bc(d)
        return d





    def algo_1(self):

        self.algo = solve_ivp(self.func,t_span=(0, self.t + .1),  y0=self.alpha, \
                   t_eval= np.array([self.t]), vectorized=True, method="LSODA")
        self.algo.y[0, 0], self.algo.y[-1, 0] =[self.b_c_start(self.t),self.b_c_end(self.t)] 
        self.approx = self.algo.y.reshape(-1, )


    def algo_2(self):


        # Finds value of y for a given x using step size h 
        # and initial value y0 at x0.

        def rungeKutta(y): 
            t = 0
            while t != self.t:
                "Apply Runge Kutta Formulas to find next value of y"
                k1 = self.H**2 * self.func(t, y) 
                k2 = self.H**2 * self.func(t + 0.5 * self.H**2, y + 0.5 * k1) 
                k3 = self.H**2 * self.func(t + 0.5 * self.H**2, y + 0.5 * k2) 
                k4 = self.H**2 * self.func(t + self.H**2, y + k3) 

                # Update next value of y 
                y = y + (1.0 / 6.0)*(k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4) 

                # Update next value of x 
                t +=  self.H**2
            return y

        self.algo = rungeKutta(self.alpha.reshape(-1, 1))
        self.algo[0, 0], self.algo[-1, 0] = [self.b_c_start(self.t),self.b_c_end(self.t)] 
        self.approx = self.algo.reshape(-1, )
```

Comment: Please see the calculations file for the phi's as I have defined in sympy  https://github.com/XtremeGood/Maths-SOP/tree/corrected_boundary_conditions

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).